# Office Mail App Message ID

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365

I was using an Office 365 trial developer account and created an app with Visual Studio 2012. I was wondering:

When composing a message, before sending the email, does it have a message id that I can get using Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId?

Can I get the itemId when the message is saved or are sent emails the only ones with message IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can't even directly create a new email with a Mail App.  You have to use the Mailbox.makeEWSRequestAsync call and use the CreateItem method from Exchange Web Services.  But AFAIK the itemid isn't available until the item is saved.

Comment: Ah, ok. As long as the saved message has an item id.